# Java, How can I use Jackson ObjectMapper to deserialize a double nested json list

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I'm trying to deserialize json objects with the following structure:

```
{"results":{  
  "Assessments":{  
     "Assessment":[  
        {  
           "assessor":"",
           "buildingName":"Emerald Palace Project",
           "certBody":"",
           ...
```

The top level is a single entity named "results" which contains "assessments" which are just a list/array of "assessment."

I've tried multiple combinations of mapper configuration such as:

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

But no matter how I switch it up I keep getting a Results object with null Assessments.

Here are my object classes using Lombok.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Results {
    private Assessments assessments;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Assessments {
    private List<Assessment> assessments;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Assessment {
    private int parentId;
    private String stage;
    private String notes;
    private String rating;
    private String scheme;
}
```

I feel like I must be missing a piece.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear: you wrote that

> […] "assessments" which are just a list/array of "assessment."

and your POJOs reflect that... then your JSON has to be…

```
{"results":{  
    "Assessments":{  
        [  
            {  
                "assessor":"",
                "buildingName":"Emerald Palace Project",
                "certBody":"",
                ...
```

…instead of…

```
{"results":{  
    "Assessments":{  
        "Assessment":[  
            {  
                "assessor":"",
                "buildingName":"Emerald Palace Project",
                "certBody":"",
                ...
```

Watch out for the list directly in "Assessments".
Also mind that your POJO fields are lowercase and so have to be your JSON keys.

So to match POJO with JSON you have various options:

- change your JSON keys to lowercase and camelcase
- use `@JsonProperty("field-name")` to match your JSON keys
- …

But in each case you have to be aware of the current clash regarding the Assessments/Assessments list.

Comment: Thanks for the step forward.  Altering the json did work, however what I'm receiving is from a third party API and so unchangeable.  But that hint did get me going in the right direction thank you.

Comment: It's usually also possible to add intermediate level(s) to match the structure. This leads to unnecessary layers but usually simplifies modeling.

Answer (score 0):

So because I had to work with the json given to me by the third party API, altering the json was not an option.

Here's how I got this working.

First off I had to change the Assessments object to have a list with a singular name. "assessment" instead of "assessments" as that is how it was spelled in the json response.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
static class Assessments {
    private List<Assessment> assessment;
}
```

Also I set up my ObjectMapper to ignore case and unknown properties.  Making sure to use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.

```
private static ObjectMapper getJsonMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
    return mapper;
}
```

The biggest change however was the introduction of a container class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
private static class JsonContainer {
    private Results results;
}
```

This class was required as it held the top level json object "Results."

After these changes were in place I got the Java objects in the state I expected.